# Node js socket.io need to validate request and server response

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a simple application to stream the stock market rates for clients. I have a source live stock rates and I need to push to all my clients.I have written in laravel api to read source rate and store into redis db and when ever new rates receive from source pushing redis changes to event so that I can push rate changes to client via socket io.
My socket io code is,

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis({ port: 6379 } );

    redis.subscribe('mcxratesupdate', function(err, count) {
        console.log('redis connected');
    });

    redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        //console.log(data);
        io.emit(channel + ':' + data.event, data.data);
    });
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    //console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3002, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3002');
});
```

This code simple working as who ever connect the client in below code it will server to all the client.

```
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://server:3002/');
    socket.on("mcxratesupdate:App\\Events\\MCXRateUpdates", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

But I have to validate the request and need to response only for my valid clients. Is it possible like validating request from array of domain and establish the connection only for valid clients and streaming the data to them.
I tried to read request header but I couldn't do that, could you please any one can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number to authentication libraries available, JWT is my favorite. When the client is sending a request, you need to pass the authentication token inside the header. After the server receives the request, you can use a middle-ware and check if the request is from a valid user or not.